# Dell Latitude 7490 laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 black screen when locked

Tags: 18.04, screen, lock-screen, wakeup, gnome-screensaver

My Dell Latitude 7490 running Ubuntu 18.04 (dock with USB-C) goes black with no way of turning it back on, whenever I lock it. Sometimes the screen goes black instantly, sometimes it goes to the lock screen and goes black after a while...

Here's a GIF of the problem:

[image: GIF of the problem]

Examples of solutions that I have tried:

- [Ubuntu 18.04 won't wake after screen lock | Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442057/ubuntu-18-04-wont-wake-after-screen-lock-and-blank-suspend-sleep),
- [Dell XPS 9370, Ubuntu 18.04 - Black screen waking up from sleep? | Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/9526sv/dell_xps_9370_ubuntu_1804_black_screen_waking_up/)

[Similar bug on Ubuntu 16.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1617471)

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, same hardware, same OS. There is a thread on the Dell community page with two other people with the same problem [here](https://www.dell.com/community/Latitude/Latitude-7490-CPU-failure-occurs-after-sleep/td-p/7316847).

Their issues seem to be resolved after [enabling tlp](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html) and replacing the motherboard. Enabling tlp with

```
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

seems to have solved the issue waking from sleep for me, though at the time of posting this, it has only been about 12 hours. It doesn't solve the other issue detailed in the Dell Community thread, though.

Comment: I don't see how replacing the motherboard solves this... It seems like a software-hardware issue. I just installed tlp and hope this will fix blank screen issues. I'm tired of putting to sleep my laptop using only the sleep button. Closing the lid is so much simpler...